# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure in JDK1.8.0_151 but not in JDK1.8.0_231 and JDK1.8.0_275

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-cloud-feign

I use org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient to request a GET from a server.

When I use Postman to check it works fine. But when it comes to FeignClient it throws an exception with jre/jdk1.8.0_151:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

However, when I use jre1.8.0_231 or jre1.8.0_275 it works fine.

Note: I send my request to a Twistlock server with an example code as follows(accurate according to simple tutorials):

```
@FeignClient(name = "TwistlockApiClient", url = "${tw.url}", fallback = TwFallback.class)
public interface FooClient {
@GetMapping(path = {"/bar"}, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
Response getBar(@bar...);
}
```

So, my question is why this happens, and is there a solution besides changing jre/jdk version?

Comment: Try running with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` or `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose` and see where / why the handshake is failing.

Comment: Only looking at the server log will tell for sure, but one possibility is that 8u151 is the last version that by default imposes the 'limited' crypto policy, preventing use of 256-bit ciphers, and some servers (or their admins/regulators) today require 256-bit for fear of unpredictable advances in the practicality of quantum cryptanalysis. You could try running sslscan or nmap or similar against the server, or if it is public www.ssllabs.com, to see what ciphersuites work. If so in 8u151 you can change the policy as described in the release notes. Missing SNI might also be a possibility.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your responses. I tried to set these flags but on the client-side, it only says the handshake fail code is 40 (which I guess the code for handshake_fail in the standard). Should I inspect the server or am I missing something?